# Why Karna didn't give Dana according to scriptures?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, karma, dharma, karna

**EXPLANATION :**

- Karna was a great man in giving **Dana to Anyone** who asks for Dana from him.
- **[Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/is-it-adharma-to-give-dana-without-considering-what-we-are-giving-and-to-whom-we)** **Support** giving Dana only to whose who that **Deserves it**.
- **Sciptures Oppose** giving Dana to whose who that does **Not deserves it** and giving to anyone is **Punisable**.
- Karna would been full aware of this rules in scriptures but he gave to anyone that asks him.
- Karna **Didn't Refuse** to **give Dana even for one time**.

  **EXAMPLE :**
- Karna gave his Kavacha and Kundala to lord indra whose **Intention was to kill karna**.

**QUESTION :**

- Why Karna didn't give Dana as said in scriptures to give only to whose who that deserves it ?
- Did he **Took a Vow** to **Give Dana to anyone** as opposing scriptures ?
- Will it cause **Bad karma** to Karna or Anyone if **Dana** is given to who that does not deserves it ?

Comment: how is indra unworthy of that dana?

Comment: @Yogi indra got it only to make arjuna win and imagine a person getting a Dana from us  to kill us

Comment: But Dharma shastras don't say that the person like Indra (vedic god) is not  eligible for accepting dana.

Comment: @Yogi friend i was not saying indra is not eligible to get dana but i am saying he got dana from karna  only to kill karna

Comment: After you explanation "which says Karna was full aware of this rules..." "Karna didn't refuse to give dana for even one time". You've added Indra's example "Karna giving his kavacha and kundala..." which is obvious that your are pointing towards Indra's eligibility to take dana. You haven't mentioned that Indra's case is not about ineligibility but its about intentions of taking dana.

Comment: @yogi yes you are correct friend i should change it and thanks friend

Comment: @Yogi is it ok now friend

Comment: I think he was bound by his nature which is of a DanaVeera..And i think most of the times he was giving charities to Brahmins too which the Scriptures approve of

Comment: I think questions such as "Why someone (Karna, Arjuna etc.) didn't follow scriptures?" will lead to opinion-based answers!

Comment: @sv. friend If arjuna gave dana against scriptures i wouldn't be this much confused but KARNA was greatly known for his DANA and a man like him giving DANA against scriptures brings the confusion

Comment: Who n how to decide deserves or not ? criteria pls

Comment: @KaushikThanki friend The link in answer tells to those who that deserves it. For Example : if we give weapon to adhamic person he will do more adharma with it. If we give weapon to a dharma(Not completely) person then it will be used for society use. So a person's guna and his motivation,etc,... decides that he DESERVES or NOT

Comment: Good question! But then we all know Karna was not always supporting or following the right Dharma. Most of his life decisions were based on emotion and perhaps the desire to be known always as Danveer prompted his decision.

Answer (score 2):

**Why Karna didn't give Dana as said in scriptures to give only to whose who that deserves it :**

It's May be just because Indra deserves the Dana and it's was required to save his own son Arjun.

**Did he Took a Vow to Give Dana to anyone as opposing scriptures ?**
Never read something like that anywhere.

**Will it cause Bad karma to Karna or Anyone if Dana is given to who that does not deserves it ?** 
Only If it was intentionally for someone's bad.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! The answers you have provided is  without sources and one-liners.On this site answers should be backed by citing sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Mahabharata , Ramayana , Gita etc. In its present form the answer is more like your personal comments. Pls. add some sources in your answer. Visit - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer