# If giving Dana to anyone is adharma then why temples give AnnaDana to anyone?

Tags: scripture, temple, practice, dharma, tradition

**EXPLANATION :**

- [Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/is-it-adharma-to-give-dana-without-considering-what-we-are-giving-and-to-whom-we) oppose giving Dana to those who that does not deserves it.
- In temples AnnaDana is given to Anyone who comes to the temple.
- In my personal experience i had seen many people who stay near the temple and live by it as **3 TIMES** a day **Anna Dana** is given.
- These kinds of activities can make a person to become **Lazy** and give up work

**QUESTION :**

- Why **Temples** where learned **Brahmins** are **Present** follow this way of giving Dana to **Anyone** ?
- Is there any **Previlage to AnnaDana** besides the other Danas (Money,Land,etc,..) ?

Comment: it is true you have to give to the deserving. so what is the criteria for a recipient to deserve food ? the answer is hunger. if a person is hungry, then he is deserving of anna danam. nowadays people can misuse it. also there are many other rules being flouted in temples e.g loud speakers blare the chanting of mantras and pranavam by anyone. i dont think brahmins have power to stop it since these activities are bankrolled by trustees/hr&ce/govt

Comment: @ram yes i agree  with you completely

Comment: Anna Dana is one of the responsibilities of the temples as per scriptures. Offering food to a person irrespective of their condition is considered good by scriptures, no scriptures are against AnnaDana

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Temples don't donate food to anyone.They donate food to those who come asking for it and obviously these people are in need of it too and understandably poor.

I will show, in what follows, that by virtue of being poor and in need of food ,they are qualified as worthy recipients of Dana.

> If you have but a morsel of food, **why don't you give half of it to the
>   poor ?** Will any body ever get his wished-for riches in this life ?
>   (23)
>
> **Vyasa Smriti,Chapter 4,Verse 29**
>
> By an intelligent person, seeking his own well-being, these gifts and
>   others should be made **specially unto the poor**, the blind and other
>   distressed persons. (91)
>
> **Samvarta Smriti,Chapter 1,Verse 91**
>
> O Vasava, O foremoost of the Celestials, **eternal is the gift that is
>   made unto a person who is** well-read in the Vedas, born in a good
>   family, **poor**, contented, humble, given to the well-being of all
>   creatures, who studies the Vedas, performs penances..
>
> **Vrihaspati Smriti,Chapter 1**

So,it is clear that, one of the qualities that make the recipient of Dana worthy, is being poor.

Also,the poor and needy are included among the *Poshyas*.The society has the responsibility of taking care of their needs,taking care of them.So,the Temples are doing Punya karma only by feeding them.

> The father, the mother, the preceptor, the wife, the children, **the
>   poor people,** the dependents, the incomers and the guests, are spoken
>   of as the Poshyas (i.e., **those who should be supported** . (29)
>
> **Daksha Smriti,Chapter 2,Verse 29**

Some further relevant verses are given below:

> **What is presented as a gift** to the father, to the mother, to the
>   .preceptor, to a friend, to a humble person, to one who has done any
>   good, **to the poor, to the helpless** and to distinguished persons,
>   **yields fruits**. (15)
>
> **Daksha Smriti, Chapter 3,Verse 15**
>
> Sandhya adorations, bathing, recitation of the Homa, Vedic study,
>   adorations of the Deities, adoration of the Vis'wadevas, hospitable
>   treatment extended to the guests, according to one's own might, **proper
>   allotment of food for the** departed Manes, Deities, human beings, the
>   **poor, the helpless**, the ascetics, the father, the mother and the
>   preceptor, **these are the nine [sacred] works.**
>
> **Daksha Smriti,Chapter 3**
>
> One desiring for lordly powers, **should make gifts unto the poor, the
>   helpless** and the learned. By making gifts unto unworthy persons,
>   people are born dependant on another's fortune.
>
> **Daksha Smriti**

So,as you can see, by simply being poor and in need of food they should be considered as worthy recipient of Dana as opposed to an unworthy one.

Also,one of the rules for Anna Dana is that it should not be made unasked for.So,here too the Temple authorities are not in fault.They are donating food to only those who are asking for it.

> Ayaachtaani deyaani sarva daanaani yatnatah, Annam Vidyaaha
>   Kanyaachahyanarthibhyona deeyate| Dvaamimau purushaa loke
>   swargasyopari tishthatah, Anna pradaataa durbhikshe subhikshe hema
>   vastradah ||
>
> Shandalya Muni mentions that all types of charities be offered without
>   being asked for and with clean conscience or with no view of securing
>   returns; **however Vidya, Kanya and Anna must not be offered without
>   being asked for as a rule!** Indeed, there are two types of charity
>   givers who attain Swarga for sure: those who heartily give away Food
>   during Durbhiksha and also those who happily give away gold and
>   clothing during the days of general prosperity

With the last quote being taken from the book ["Essence of Dharma Bindu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf) .

And ,moreover,the Temples distribute the Prasadam and not just any food.So,the act is even more sacred and beneficial for everyone involved.

Comment: if one  does not desrves dana but asks for dana we should not give it right

Comment: No we shd not but a poor is already a deserving candidate..so is the one who does not have the money to buy food..

Comment: @Sakthi Also i think the temples distribute the prasadam..So,its even more punya karma..

Comment: i am asking about a man who is not poor by situation but due to his laziness he doesn't go to work but come to temple and get food so does he deserves it ?

Comment: @Sakthi Haha..I don't think there will be some persons like that who is not poor but goes to temples just for getting a free lunch..Even if there r, they will be one in many..So just for the sake that one pervert all the other poor shd not be deprived IMO..

Comment: yes you are correct there are only two or three so majority is important and i suggest you to add prasadam in your answer