# How to identify the person who asks for Dana deserve or not?

Tags: karma, dharma

I saw [Is it adharma to give Dana without considering what we are giving and to whom we are giving?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/is-it-adharma-to-give-dana-without-considering-what-we-are-giving-and-to-whom-we)

But When we give Dana to some person, how to find that person deserved dana or not? Some looks like poor [but they may be rich, we don't know], so when they asked us, what should be done?