# Donating money or food to beggars, and its karmic results

Tags: karma, reference-request

I have heard that it is better to donate food (or clothes etc.), instead of money, to beggars.

The reason is that if the beggars mislead the donor into thinking that they will use the money to buy food, but instead use it to purchase alcoholic beverages or use it for other unbeneficial things like gambling, the donor will still experience the negative karmic consequences, due to having contributed money towards it. This is despite the fact that the donor did not have the intention to support the purchase of alcohol or the act of gambling.

Questions:

1. Is this in accordance with the Hindu doctrine on karma and its fruits?
2. What would be your advice to potential donors?

If possible, please support your answers with scriptural references.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be in accordance to our scriptures, and usually applied to monetary donations...
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/is-it-adharma-to-give-dana-without-considering-what-we-are-giving-and-to-whom-we 
My advice is to donate food (AnnaDaan) such as fruits/vegetables to beggars, or donate money to organizations sponsoring education.